# Update Models in Controller with Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to update these models with Linq to sql, but I can't. There are so many props in the models. So I do not want to match one by one.How can I Update my Models?

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(MyModal1 m1, MyModel2 m2)
    {
        MyModel1 willBeUpdatedm1= ctx.MyModal1.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == 
        m1.id);
        MyModel2 willBeUpdatedm2= ctx.MyModal2.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == 
        m2.id);

        return RedirectToAction("Update", new {m1.id });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own implementation by iterating through properties with reflection (e.g. konut.GetType().GetProperties() and then iterate through all properties and setting them for Db model) or you could use some 3rd party tools to do mapping for you. For example AutoMapper (https://automapper.org/) or ValueInjecter (https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter). They both do pretty good job, although I think ValueInjecter is simpler to begin with.

Here you have sample when using ValueInjecter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KonutGuncelle(Konut konut, KonutOzellik ko)
{
    KonutOzellik willBeUpdatedko = ctx.KonutOzellik.SingleOrDefault(x => x.KonutOzellikID == konut.KonutOzellikID);
    willBeUpdatedko.InjectFrom(ko); // New code with ValueInjecter

    Konut willBeUpdatedkonut = ctx.Konut.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == konut.id);
    willBeUpdatedko.InjectFrom(konut); // New code with ValueInjecter

    ctx.SaveChanges(); // Must save changes?

    return RedirectToAction("KonutGuncelle", new { konut.id });
}
```

Comment: Or you could use what Entity Framework already provides by using `ctx.Entry(konut).State = EntittyState.Modified` and forget about both third party libraries and reflection